# angularjs - bootbox callback issue

Tags: angularjs, bootbox

I have a view with two tabs, in first tab I have the text input commentaireLien.

In the controller, when I enter in the bootbox confirm callback , the input commentaireLiens is not refreshed(with "test") in the browser.
If I go in another tab in the view and then go back in the tab that contains commentaireLiens, then it gets refreshed.

I don't understand why.

```
bootbox.confirm({
    size: "small",
    message: "Voulez-vous valider le CV ?",
    callback: function (result) {
        if (result) {
            vm.commentaireLiens ="test";
        } 
    }
})
```

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="commentaireLiens"
       id="field_commentaireLiens"
       ng-model="vm.commentaireLiens"
/>
```

Comment: Does it work if you remove the if clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bootbox.confirm({
    size: "small",
    message: "Voulez-vous valider le CV ?",
    callback: function (result) {
        if (result) {
            vm.commentaireLiens ="test";
            $scope.$apply();
        } 
    }
})
```

AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc... You can also use `$apply()` to enter the AngularJS execution context from JavaScript.

Keep in mind that in most places (controllers, services) `$apply` has already been called for you by the directive which is handling the event. An explicit call to `$apply` is **needed only when** implementing custom event callbacks, or when **working with third-party library callbacks**.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Integration with the browser event loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#integration-with-the-browser-event-loop)
- [AngularJS $scope/$rootScope API Reference - $apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply)